# NSDateFormatter returning wrong minutes

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I am converting a server timestamp that is a NSString to a NSDate however I am getting the wrong time. Please help. Here is my code.

```
NSLog(@"string %@", string);

// Setup Date Formatter
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.zzzZ"];

// Get Date From String
NSDate *dateOfCall = [formatter dateFromString:string];
NSLog(@"dateOfCall %@",dateOfCall);

[formatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:dateOfCall];
NSLog(@"dateString %@",dateString);
```

And this is my log.

```
string 2015-05-19T01:48:33.603890Z
dateOfCall 2015-05-19 01:38:29 +0000
dateString 9:38 PM
```

As you can tell it seems to be converting the minutes wrong.

Comment: Did you not consult any sort of spec for the date format???

Comment: I did consult this link http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns. However you can only do so much with it if you don't fully understand how the timezone codes work.

Comment: It makes no sense to combine two different timezone codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date formatter is not right,try this one

```
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ"];
```

And this will output

```
2015-05-19 10:31:04.530 OCTest[2428:76257] string 2015-05-19T01:48:33.603890Z
2015-05-19 10:31:04.534 OCTest[2428:76257] dateOfCall 2015-05-19 01:48:33 +0000
2015-05-19 10:31:35.113 OCTest[2428:76257] dateString 9:48 AM
```

I am not sure if this is what you want,if you have more questions,feel free to comment